# How do I convert percentage into a range of numbers?

Tags: java, math, jframe

I know this probably isn't very hard, but I need to convert a percentage into a range of numbers. I am making a test right now, and I want to display a progress bar of sorts. The bar starts at (75, 425) and goes to (625, 425) on my JFrame. So the range of x values would be from 75 to 625. I want the left side of the screen to be 0% and the right side to be 100%. I would draw a line on the bar wherever the percentage was. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Could you use a [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) rather than write your own version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the x value you simply take the following equation:

```
x = left + percentage/100 * (right-left)
```

with the numbers you provided filled in it looks like this:

```
x = 75 + percentage/100 * (625 - 75)
```

Keep in mind that this is not doable with only integer arithmetic since `percentage/100` results in a value in the rage of 0..1 and therefore should be float or double.

You should consider using a JProgressBar as [suggested by Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119090/how-do-i-convert-percentage-into-a-range-of-numbers/34119147#34119147).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the JProgressBar for that purpose.

You won't need to know the position of the Bar, all you have to do is add a propertyChangedListener.

I recommend reading : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html